# Get all data for users Djoser

Tags: django, djoser

I use userProfile model the following code. It has "OneToOneField" for djoser auth_user. I want gel all data for users.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class userProfile(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="profile")
    date_joined=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and seralizers class show in bellow;

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import userProfile
class userProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=userProfile
        fields='__all__'
```

I want to get all users using ;

```
class userAccountsListView(ListAPIView):

    queryset=userProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class=userProfileSerializer
```

It return data like;

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date_joined": "2020-04-16T16:50:38.218964+03:00",
        "updated_on": "2020-04-16T16:50:38.218996+03:00",
        "user": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date_joined": "2020-04-30T13:53:48.859116+03:00",
        "updated_on": "2020-04-30T13:53:48.859149+03:00",
        "user": 6
    }
]
```

I want to get all users info;

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date_joined": "2020-04-16T16:50:38.218964+03:00",
        "updated_on": "2020-04-16T16:50:38.218996+03:00",
        "user": 5,
        "first_name": "xxxxx",
        "last_name": "xxxxx",
        "email":"xxxx",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date_joined": "2020-04-30T13:53:48.859116+03:00",
        "updated_on": "2020-04-30T13:53:48.859149+03:00",
        "user": 6,
        "first_name": "xxxxx",
        "last_name": "xxxxx",
        "email":"xxxx",

    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the own CurrentUserSerializer.

```
class CurrentUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'id','first_name','last_name')

class userProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=CurrentUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=userProfile
        fields='__all__
```

I get json output;

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "username": "x",
        "email": "x",
        "id": 5,
        "first_name": "x",
        "last_name": "x"
    },
    "date_joined": "2020-04-16T16:50:38.218964+03:00",
    "updated_on": "2020-04-16T16:50:38.218996+03:00"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "user": {
        "username": "x",
        "email": "x",
        "id": 6,
        "first_name": "x",
        "last_name": "x"
    },
    "date_joined": "2020-04-30T13:53:48.859116+03:00",
    "updated_on": "2020-04-30T13:53:48.859149+03:00"
}
```

]